amazon chime sdk jsをビルドした際にエラー('.' is not recognized as an internal or external command)
gitからcloneした amazon-chime-sdk-js をビルドした際に下記「'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command」エラーが発生します。実行PCはWindowsです。
試した事

npm install -g typescript を実行
generate-red-worker-code.js 内の対象パス(runCommandWithLogs('./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --build config/tsconfig.red.json');)をCドライブからの絶対パスに変更。

いずれも改善につながりませんでした。
解決方法が分かる方いらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけますと幸いです。
git/amazon-chime-sdk-js (main)
$ npm run build

> amazon-chime-sdk-js@3.22.0 prebuild
> ruby script/conditional-install

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 615 packages, and audited 616 packages in 13s

54 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Running npm ci to regenerate node_modules.
--> npm ci

> amazon-chime-sdk-js@3.22.0 build
> node script/barrelize.js && node script/generate-version.js && npm run red && npm run tsc:src && npm run tsc:guides && npm run copy

Build description: {
  "hash": "4a9dd14",
  "raw": "v3.22.0",
  "semverString": "3.22.0"
}

> amazon-chime-sdk-js@3.22.0 red
> node script/generate-red-worker-code.js


> amazon-chime-sdk-js@3.22.0 prebuild
> ruby script/conditional-install

node_modules is up to date.

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Error: Command failed: ./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --build config/tsconfig.red.json
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


恐らく Windows で実行しているように見えますが、該当のリポジトリでは Issue も起票されているようです。Fails to build on Windows 10 #2779 / Linux 系の OS じゃないと対応してない可能性もあります。

Windowsで実行しています。
